# AddThis buttons

Tags: html, addthis

I'm working on a basic HTML site for photo galleries and I want to add AddThis buttons but they won't show up.

I am using this code:

```
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
  <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-52adbb04690060bb"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

But nothing shows up on the webpage. At times I get text links instead of buttons. I have tried the troubleshooting steps that is suggested on their site but it's not helping.

[AddThis Troubleshooting](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1296783-troubleshooting-connectivity-issues#.Uq34Y_RDt8E)

[AddThis Debugging](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1296781-debugging-css-javascript#.Uq34DPRDt8E)

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into jsfiddle and it worked for me.

Comment: That's bizzare. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was viewing the html file directly from the filesystem at `file:///home/emmanuel/html/new.html` and not through a web server. Putting the html file in an apache server directory (/var/www in ubuntu) and viewing it at `http://127.0.0.1/new.html` solved the issue for me. Hope this helps.

new.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:layout="horizontal"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-52b7262c326d06b2"></script>
    <!-- AddThis Button END -->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
    <script>
        (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
        function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
        e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
        e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
        r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
        ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');
    </script>
</body>
```